# Problems when displaying custom view when fire localnotification

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I am trying to display a custom view once a notification is fired on the iPhone. By that I mean, once the UILocalNotification alert pops up and the user presses the action button, right now it shows my main view but I'd rather have it show a different view.

How do I accomplish that? Don't necessarily need code, just the general steps to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when notification arrives on device or when you launch the app fron action of notification alert...

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo { 
//code to navigate
}
```

method get's called .
so you need to write code to navigate to your code in that method.